# Exp-resso Store: Shipping Country Options

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

How can I grab store's shipping country options in a template without a store tag? I would like to use them in a custom signup form.

Comment: Florian, did you get this to work (also with Store II)?

Comment: Not really, I ended up doing something different. I believe I used a matrix with the values. And a little later the project got abandoned because of reasons outside of my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store wont support that natively as far as I know but I'd personally look to use [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) to set a variable and then call it either elsewhere in that template or carry across to other templates.

Setting the variable is as pretty much as simple as `{exp:stash:set}` giving it a name and setting a few specific options, and then calling it with `{exp:stash:get}`. It's incredibly versatile.

**Example:**

```
{exp:store:checkout}
    ...

    {!-- Set the variable --}
    {exp:stash:set name="shipping_methods" save="yes"}{field:shipping_method}{/exp:stash:set}

    ...
{/exp:store:checkout}

{!-- Get the variable outside of the Store tags --}
{exp:stash:get name="shipping_methods"}
```

**EDIT:** Updated example to include save="yes" to demonstrate how to carry variable through to other template files.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of how this would work? I cannot envision it.

Comment: Updated with example. The benefits of Stash will mean a second query isn't run within your templates and you can take advantage of caching and even pass that variable along to other templates.

Comment: As far as I can see this would not enable me to use the shipping countries in other templates, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: As I said, you can carry it across to other templates if you wish to do so. You just need [save="yes"](https://github.com/croxton/Stash#save--yesno) to the Stash set tag (example updated). It's all in the Stash docs.

Comment: `{field:shipping_methods}` is probably not the tag you would want to use though as that would list the shipping gateways you have setup. You would want to use `{field:shipping_country}` and `{field:shipping_region}`

Comment: I'd missed save="yes". Very interesting!

Comment: Small but vital. :) It just tells Stash that you want to save it to the database to persist across pages. Glad you got it working.

Comment: One more question: When does this variable get saved / updated? On pageload?

Comment: Yep. Basically when the page is parsed. The values can then be cached for re-use in that template or others.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Query Module to grab the available regions are.

```
<select>
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_store_regions WHERE site_id = '1' GROUP BY country_code"}
<option value="{region_code}">
 {region_name}
</option>
{/exp:query}
</select>
```

Comment: That might work for regions, but not for countries. In exp_store_countries only the country codes are saved. Where does Store's {billing_country_options} get the country names?

Comment: The countries are generated from the countries.php file that comes with EE

Comment: Has anyone tinkered with Peter Lewis's plugin[1] for Store 1.6+ to make this compatible with V2+?


  [1]: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-address-lists

Comment: I have not personally but it should be pretty easy to do if you have an understanding of PHP.